# IMG SRC tags and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, image

Is it possible to call a JavaScript function from the IMG SRC tag to get an image url?

Like this:

```
<IMG SRC="GetImage()" />

<script language="javascript">
   function GetImage() {return "imageName/imagePath.jpg"}
</script>
```

This is using .NET 2.0.

Comment: The question doesn't really outline what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Agreed - it took me a minute to figure out what he was getting at...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Nope.  It's not possible, at least not in all browsers.  You can do something like this instead:

```
<img src="blank.png" id="image" alt="just nothing">
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('image').src = "yourpicture.png";
</script>
```

Your favourite JavaScript framework will provide nicer ways :)

Answer (score 11):

If you're in the mood for hacks, this works as well.

```
<img src='blah' onerror="this.src='url to image'">
```

Answer (score 9):

> Is it possible to call a JavaScript function from the IMG SRC tag to get an image url?

Do you mean doing something like the following?

```
<img src="javascript:GetImage()" />
```

Unfortunately, no - you can't do that. However, you can do the following hack:

```
function getImageUrl(img) {
   var imageSrc = "imageName/imagePath.jpg";
   if(img.src != imageSrc) { // don't get stuck in an endless loop
      img.src = imageSrc;
   }
}
```

Then, have the following html:

```
<img src="http://yourdomain.com/images/empty.gif" onload="getImageUrl(this)" />
```

The onload event will only fire if you have an actual image set to the src attribute - if you don't set that attribute or set it to an empty string or something similar, you will get no love. Set it to a single pixel transparent gif or something similar.

Anyway, this hack works, but depending on what you are really trying to accomplish, this may not be the best solution. I don't know why you would want to do this, but maybe you have a good reason (that you would like to share with us!).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it inline the image @src, but you should be able to call it from an inline script block immediately following your image:

```
<img src="" id="myImage"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("myImage").src = GetImage();
</script>
```

Comment: Opera doesn't support inline script tags? This is news to me.

Comment: That's actually far from the truth.  It's recommended to place script tags as far down in your page as possible, since DOM rendering is delayed until the script has finished executing.  You can really speed up perceived page load time by placing script tags at the end of your body.

Answer (score 1):

you could dynamically feed the image by calling an aspx page in the SRC.

Ex;

```
<img src="provideImage.aspx?someparameter=x" />
```

On the page side, you`ll need to put the image in the response and change the content type for an image.

The only "problem" is that your images won't be indexed a you better put some cache on that provider page or you'll ravage the server.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this.src ?`

```
<img src='images/test.jpg' onmouseover="alert(this.src);">
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using .NET, you could add the `runat="server"` attribute and set the `src` in your codebehind.

Answer (score 0):

You **might** be able to do it on the server side.  Alternately you could attach an onload event to swap the image src out.  I guess the question then becomes, why would you have to use Javascript in the first pace?

Answer (score 0):

I've had to do something like this before, and IIRC the trick winds up being that you can't change an src attribute of an image that's part of the DOM tree.  So your best bet is to write your HTML skeleton without the image and 1)create an onLoad function that generates a new img element with document.createElement, 2) set the src attribute with setAttribute(), and 3) attach it to your DOM tree.

Answer (score 0):

OnLoad event of image called again and again do some thing like this

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
var imgsBlocks = new Array( '/1.png', '/2.png', '/3.png');
function getImageUrl(elemid) {  
var ind = document.getElementById(elemid).selectedIndex;
document.getElementById("get_img").src=imgsBlocks[ind]; 
}
```

it's not work?

```
<img src="'+imgsBlocks[2]+'" id="get_img"/>
```

Comment: That assumes that you are building the HTML in your JS code; There is no hint in the question that this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this way also

```js
const myImage = new Image(200, 200);
myImage.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,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';
document.body.appendChild(myImage);
```

Answer (score -1):

No.  The Img's SRC attribute is not an event, therefore the inline JS will never fire.

Comment: It does,  however, take a URI and can run javascript: pseudo-URIs. This is a cause of XSS holes.

Answer (score -1):

OnLoad event of image called again and again do some thing like this