# Variable for img src=

Tags: javascript, image, src

I have a question. 
Firstly, I am not going to pretend that I know what I am talking about here. I am a newbie to http and JavaScript.

I think my question may be answered in this post
[IMG SRC tags and JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116967/img-src-tags-and-javascript)
but I thought I would explain the exact thing I am trying to achieve in case there is an easier way.

I have a webpage, I want to display an image on it. Only thing is, the image is coming from an automated system monitor, the image is automatically generated each day and placed in a new directory depending on date.

e.g. On April 4 = "http://host/partition/2009/apr/04/cpu.gif"
e.g. On April 5 = "http://host/partition/2009/apr/05/cpu.gif"

To facilitate this, I have created some basic JavaScript to give me the date in the format I need it. I have all that working. Now I just want to use that variable I created to show the image. 
I have the JavaScript code stored in a function called displaydate() 
If I do this `<script language="JavaScript"> displaydate() </script>`  I see 
"http://host/partition/2009/apr/05/cpu.gif"  and that is correct.

Now how do I display this on the site correctly?

```
 <a href="displaydate()"><img src="displaydate()" </a></td>    //This does not work. I am just adding it to show where I have been heading.
```

P.S. I have read a lot of pages on this and been trying a lot of things, but have had no luck so far. Any help, would be much appreciated.

Comment: you mention Java - is your question how to output the variable into the src attribute? Are you using something like JSP?

Comment: Javascript has nothing to do with Java. I think you have confused the two.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, that page probably does answer your question.  Basically, you want this javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('image').src = "yourpicture.png";
</script>
```

Except you want to replace the "yourpicture.png" with the function you wrote to generate the correct path to the image on disk, so...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('image').src = displaydate();
</script>
```

Of course, you might need to modify this a bit for your own uses, the getElementById will take as an argument whatever the id attribute of your < img > tag is. You probably want to execute the above javascript after your page has loaded, i.e.:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function load()
{
document.getElementById('image').src = displaydate();
}

function displaydate()
{
//your displaydate() function here
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="load()">

<img src="nothing.jpg" id="image" name="image"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Far out, thanks for the response. I was not expecting such a quick reply. This is the first time I have asked a question on any forum. Thanks, I will try this out.

Comment: Welcome, just made another edit that i actually tested and it worked for me.  Hopefully you can get yours working. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You should just need to change this line

```
document.write("http://host1/Shared/" + year + "/" + month + "/" + day + "/cpu_abs.gif");
```

to

```
return "http://host1/Shared/" + year + "/" + month + "/" + day + "/cpu_abs.gif";
```