# IMG SRC and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to javascript and I'm trying to learn.
I'd like my webpage to dynamically show an image from another parent site based on the actual data.
I tried to create the function to get the variables I need in order to get the image at the correct url
I read [Variable for img src=](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767143/variable-for-img-src) but I got lost, then I tried to do something like this

```
function LoadPage() { 
var today = new Date(); 
var yyyy = today.getFullYear(); 
var mm = (today.getMonth()+ 1); 
var dd = (today.getDate(); 

img.src = "http://www.parentsite.com/"+yyyy+"_"+mm+"_"+dd+"/images.png"();
}

</script>
```

Could anyone please help me with this?
Thank you

Comment: Remove the parenthesis "()" at the end of img.src assignment.

Comment: Agree with @Abbas - also remove the leading "(" from the dd assignment and (optional) leading and trailing parentheses from the mm assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function LoadPage() { 
var today = new Date(); 
var yyyy = today.getFullYear(); 
var mm = (today.getMonth()+ 1); 
var dd = today.getDate(); 
var url = "http://www.parentsite.com/"+yyyy+"_"+mm+"_"+dd+"/images.png";
alert(url);
document.getElementById("img").setAttribute("src",url);
}
```

Assuming your image tag has the id img, the alert line should tell you wether you are setting up your image path correctly

Comment: Thank you, the alert was useful, I missed a character in the path.         <body onload="LoadPage()"> completed the task.I cannot vote the answer because I'm new.

Answer (score 0):

The var img needs to be a pointer to an asset for example an image so that you can assign the asset a src attribute with the method setAttribute("src",url). Maybe you have forgot to assign img = getElementByName("myasset")?