# Put source of HTML5 video in JS variable

Tags: javascript, html, variables

This is my video.

```
<video id="myVideo" controls autoplay>
 <source id="mp4_src" src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
```

Using JS, how do I read the source of the video and put that URL into a variable?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767143/variable-for-img-src

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not plan to use jQuery or other library, you can use cods like:

```
document.getElementById("myVideo").children[0].getAttribute("src");
```

please aware that children[0], this index related on the "source" node's position in "video"'s children, if you add other child node into video.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `currentSrc` property of the video object.

```
var src = document.getElementById("myVideo").currentSrc;
```

The HTML5 video object has additional properties and methods that regular elements don't have. It is more appropriate to work with the video object, rather than use `getAttribute()` or `attr()`.

Answer (score -1):

this would do (using jquery):

```
var videovar = $("#mp4_src").attr("src");
```

Comment: I don't see jQuery mentioned anywhere in this question.

Comment: don't i have to include the video id?

Comment: @CodyRaspien - If jQuery is an option for you, you should update the question with that tag at least.

Answer (score -1):

Use jquery!

var url = $('#mp4_src').attr('src');

or without jquery:

document.getElementById("mp4_src").src

Comment: would be great if you could provide an explanation when downvoting