# how to display image to my <img> tag using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<img id="Preview"  style="width: 150px; height: 200px;"/>

<script>
    $("#Preview").attr('src', "pic1.png");
</script>
```

This shows an image sometimes, but after I refresh my page this image will disappear. I put this line of code into the script:

```
$("#Preview").attr('src', "pic1.png?timestamp="+new Date().getTime());
```

But it doesn't help! Can you please help me to solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28230821/how-to-display-image-to-my-img-image-tag-using-javascript

Comment: it seem to by the same like this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767143/variable-for-img-src

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   $("#Preview").prop("src", "pic1.png?timestamp="+new Date().getTime());
});
```

Note: The image URL should be correct, try to give full URL.

Answer (score 1):

1. did you use jQuery? if not, you can try like this:

```html
img = document.getElementById('yourID')
img.src = "your image url"
```

2. make sure the image path is work.