# How do I use variables in my href when downloading a file?

Tags: javascript, html, href

**JavaScript**

I have three variables that I would like to use to define the href for downloading a file:

```
var fSelect;
var uSelect;
var bSelect;
```

So my href would be defined by a variable like this:

```
var saveFile = '../files/' + fSelect + uSelect + bSelect + '.x3g';
```

**HTML**

But then how do i use this in my HTML document?

```
<a><img src="../save-button.png" alt="Save" width="120" height="40" /></a>
```

Comment: You mean change the src of the img tag?

Comment: I think this solution may help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767143/variable-for-img-src

Comment: I understand it as "how can I generate the `href` attribute of my anchor tag using the pre-defined variables ?", am I right ?

Answer (score 0):

Give the img tag an ID attribute (in this case, I'm using img)
Then modify the tag using DOM

```js
document.getElementById("img").src = saveFile;
```

Answer (score 0):

As I have understood, the question is "how to start downloading file when I have a `safeFile` variable"?

```
<a id="saveFileHref" href="#">
   <img src="../save-button.png" alt="Save" width="120" height="40" />
</a>
```

In JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('saveFileHref').onclick = function() {    
    var saveFile = '../files/' + fSelect + uSelect + bSelect + '.x3g';
    window.location.href = saveFile;
};
```

JavaScript `onclick` event lets you define a behaviour of clicked element.
`window.location.href` lets your change the current URL.

It is a good approach if your `fSelect`, `uSelect` and `bSelect` are chosen on the page and url should be generated dynamically.
If you have a calculated `safeFile` value at the beginning of loading, you can set it in the beginning:

```
document.getElementById('saveFileHref').src = '../files/' + fSelect + uSelect + bSelect + '.x3g';
```