# how can put a javascript variable in img tag

Tags: javascript

I need to put a javascript variable as image source.  That is my image tag **should be in this format**
here i am adding my script

```
document.getElementById("pricefilter").innerHTML ='<img src="variablename/spinner.gif" title="Loading..." alt="Loading...">';
```

The **variablename** carries my image path.  How can I put this in double quates.

Please help to solve this

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to do...

Answer (score 4):

Strings can be added together, if `variablename` contains the path:

```
document.getElementById("pricefilter").innerHTML ='<img src="' + variablename +
  '/spinner.gif" title="Loading..." alt="Loading...">';
```

Answer (score 2):

If i get your question correctly use

`document.getElementById("pricefilter").src=ur variable;`

One of previuos [stackoverflow ques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116967/img-src-tags-and-javascript) similar to urs showed this

```
<img src="blank.png" id="image" alt="just nothing">
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('image').src = "yourpicture.png";
</script>
```