# Is it possible to set the source of an image using the javascript: pseudo-protocol?

Tags: javascript

Basically, I have a context where I'm only allowed to create an image, but I want to run a script before I decide on the source, so I'm wondering if this is possible:

```
<img src="javascript:{load a remote script and run it to figure out the source}" />
```

The work-around that I've come up with is:

```
<img src="any-old-image.gif" onload="document.write('<scr' + 'ipt src=\"http://mysite-script.js\"'></scr' + 'pt>');" />
```

but I'm hoping something a little cleaner is possible.

P.S. I'm aware that "javascript:" is quote-unquote evil. This is a special situation.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116967

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function that gathers whatever data you need and sends it to the server (via XMLHttpRequest, or whatever method you prefer).  Create a function that examines the response from the server and decides what image to use.  You can then set the url to your image directly:

```
document.getElementById("myImage").src = myImageSrc;
```

**Edit:** Addressing comment.

If you can only muck with the img element itself, then you are right, `img.onload` is what you want.  And if there's more than just a couple of lines of script, importing the script seems reasonable.  Maybe this is a little bit cleaner than `document.write`:

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("script")).src =
    "http://mysite.com/myscript.js";
```

Comment: In order to do that, I have to have the script with the function available. In order to make that script available, it seems I need to load it via the image onload hack that I've outlined above.

Comment: @sprugman: After re-reading your post and comments, wow, those are a lot of restrictions.  Any way you accomplish it will be a "hack".  Importing the script makes sense, given your restrictions.

Comment: yeah... just thought I'd check to see if I was missing anything more elegant. Thanks, though. (I like the appendChild improvement.)

Answer (score 0):

If what you want can be done on the server.  You could just make the src attribute point your server side script and write back the image after executing whatever you want.

Not sure if that fits your issue though.

Comment: I need to gather some data on the client, then send that to the server for processing, THEN get back the real image....