# Display image based on a value in asp GridView column

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview and one of the template fields is an asp image server tag. I want to display an image in this gridview but based on the value that I obtain on databind.

So, every row can have a different values and based on these values I need to display different images. I tried to call a javascript function GetImage() and pass the value that I obtain on databind to this function. But, I cannot get this to work.

```
 <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<%$Resources:LocalizedText,LabelStatus%>">
           <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="imgStatus" runat="server" CssClass="label" src="GetImage(<%#Eval(<%# Bind("Status_value")  %>) %>)"/>
           </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
```

Javascript function -

```
function GetImage(value)
{
    if (value == 1)
    {
        return "../Images/act_green.gif";
    }
    else
    {
        return "../Images/act_red.gif";
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? And, how can I fix it? Thanks

Comment: Can you show the rendered HTML output?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unless you have more needs that you haven't mentioned, there is no need to use Javascript and you might as well do everything on the server.

Change your asp:image tag to the following:

```
<asp:Image ID="imgStatus" runat="server" CssClass="label" ImageURL='<%# GetImage((int)Eval("Status_Value")) %>' />
```

In your code-behind, place the following:

```
public static string GetImage(int value)
{
    if (value == 1)
    { 
        return "../Images/act_green.gif";
    }
    else
    {
        return "../Images/act_red.jpg";
    }
}
```

And you're done.

Comment: I was unable to use Bind or Eval to the src property of Image server tag. And, based on your answer I used ImageURL property instead and manipulated the data accordingly in my datasource (code-behind). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your *GetImage* function is not executed.

See:
[IMG SRC tags and JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116967/img-src-tags-and-javascript/118366#118366)

---

Server side code can return the path to the image without using JS.

Comment: Hmm makes sense. But, any idea how I can solve this problem? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can do it without using any javascript.