# Why are javascript: URIs allowed in the src attribute of <img> tags?

Tags: javascript, html, security, xss, image

On practically every XSS mitigation guide I've seen, the following pattern is mentioned:

```
<img src="javascript:evil();">
```

What legitimate use could this possibly have?  Can you use JS code to generate a base64-encoded representation or something?

Comment: It would seem from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116967/img-src-tags-and-javascript) that my suggestion is not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't have many legitimate uses.

The way it works is probably because you can use any protocol there, and some browsers implement the `javascript` pseudo protocol, which can be invoked from multiple places.

Comment: Modern browsers don't support the `javascript:` protocol for `<img>` elements though - try this: http://jsfiddle.net/LXwM9/

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen And Firefox disabled it for the address bar. Some browsers must still allow if for `src` attributes, it seems.

Comment: I just wouldn't call those ones the modern browsers :P

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about a legitimate use, but some browsers (usually older ones) will execute the JavaScript. [See the OWASP XSS Filter Evasion Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet#Image_XSS_using_the_JavaScript_directive).

Comment: I wanted to link to the `ha.ckers.org` XSS cheat sheet but it looks like it now redirects to the OWASP list. Too bad; I seem to remember it being more in-depth.