# Html is <img src="<script>Some javascript</script>" > allowed?

Tags: javascript, html

Is the code bellow allowed in html ?

```
<img src=<script>Some javascript</script> >
```

I know I can set attribute in javascript with setAttribute, but I would like to do it differently.

Comment: What is your requirement?

Comment: That's not valid HTML, so: no. Why do it the simple way if you can do it the hard way...? :)

Comment: if you wanna know y don't u try it yourself?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116967/img-src-tags-and-javascript

Comment: You can modify the `src` attribute using JS, but not like shown in your sample. What is it, that you actually want to achieve?

Comment: I have tried it, but it doesn't work, so I would like to know if there are maybe a syntax error or something else...
My javascript code displays the image source

Comment: You have missed quotes `<img src="<script>Some javascript</script>"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not. It is nowhere near to valid HTML, as you can check with a validator. Besides, an attribute value is taken as text; no tags are interpreted there.

To set an attribute of an HTML element in JavaScript, you can use `setAttribute` or directly assign to a property of the element node (the `src` property in this case).

You are not telling why you would not do things that way, but there is another way, though it is old-fashioned and risky: in a place where you would put an `img` element, you can write

```
document.write('<img src=' + someVariable + ' alt="">');
```

That is, you would generate the entire `img` element, in serialized form that will then be parsed by the browser.

A better way to add an element that is not in the document statically is to use `document.createElement`, do some assignments, and then add the created element into the document tree e.g. with the `appendChild` method of a suitable element.